# ListView's scrollbar is not working

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2013, picturebox, imagelist

I am currently displaying images into listView1 from imageList1; however, the scrollbar is not working at all and there are over 1300 images to display. I need the vertical scrollbar to work but no matter what I do I can not get it working. I have it Scrollable = True in the properties but it is static for some reason and I think it's because of the way the images are grabbed from the imageList1 and displayed.

```
PictureBox pb = default(PictureBox);
int x = 10, y = 3000;
foreach (Image img in imageList1.Images)
{
    pb = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    pb.Image = img;
    pb.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    pb.Width = 58;
    pb.Height = 40;
    y -= 45;
    pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    listView1.Controls.Add(pb);         
}
```

I am new to using Visual Studio 2013 and C#, this is one of my first projects and I am already stuck. Could really use someones help.

Comment: are you setting the scrollbar's scrolling vertical / horizontal property..? or 
`Listview1.Scrollable = true;`

Comment: I have tried both listView1.Scrollable = true;and listView1.Scrollable = VerticalScroll.Visible;

Comment: I have tried them too.. so what are you saying.. did it work..? or did it not work..?

Comment: Did not work, no scrollbar is displayed at all and the images just sit there running off the form not able to scroll.

Comment: Is your listView on a panel of some sort? I would try to add the scrollbar there.

Comment: No the listView is on the Form1 itself and loaded with the Form1_Load. Like I stated I am new to Visual Studio so if you can explain how the panel would allow the scroll where as the listview does not?

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale  DangerZone is referring to the Panel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx - if you set the AutoScroll property on a Panel to true, the contents of the list view will be scrollable if they "overflow" from the visible area of the panel.

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked and thanks for better explaining.

Comment: @Dev Mode One more question if I may but how would I go about displaying the filename of the image located in the imageList1? I have googled but found nothing on it. I need to display the filename next to each image it belongs to.

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale without seeing how you're loading the Images collection its hard to say, but you may be able to access it via the PIctureBox's ImageLocation property. PS - if you found any or all of the suggestions helpful, please remember to rate them up :)

Comment: The code I provided above is loaded in the private void Form1_Load so as soon as the program starts it loads the images in using the above code. All the images are located within the imageList1 control. Also I was not sure you could rate a comment vs a answer. How do I go about rating each?